# cmake including h files from other directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I am having trouble including a test under a cmake project. My project is set out like this:

```
                                       TerrainMap
                                        /     \
                         PointAccumulator     heightQuadGrid
                                                \
                                                 Test
```

In the TerrainMap Directory the CMakeLists.txt file simply outlines the cmake version the project name and includes the two sub directories.

In heightQuadGrid the CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_library(heightQuadGrid heightQuadGrid.cpp)

add_subdirectory(Test)
```

which as I understand makes a library called heightQuadGrid. The CMakeLists.txt in Test looks like this:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS} )

link_libraries(heightQuadGrid)

add_executable(heightQuadTreeTest heightQuadGridTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries (heightQuadTreeTest heightQuadGrid ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})
```

And finally the cpp file heightQuadGridTest.cpp has this include:

```
#include <heightQuadGrid/heightQuadGrid.h>
```

The cmake works correctly but when i go to make the project it tells me that it cannot find heightQuadGrid/heightQuadGrid.h

Whats the deal as I have seen a very similar approach in another working project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <heightQuadGrid/heightQuadGrid.h>
```

This syntax indicates that one of the "include directories" for the project should be the directory above the `heightQuadGrid` dir.  In the cmakelists.txt file for the `heightQuadTreeTest` executable, you need to go up two directories, and add that as an include directory:

```
include_directories(../../)
```

Comment: No I don't think so, to me this indicates i am trying to get heightQuadGrid.h from the library heightQuadGrid which i have linked appropriately.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (I don't have your directory structure on my machine) but "linking appropriately" tells the *linker* where to look... the include directories tell the *compiler* where to look.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you mean, but would i need to include 2 directories up or just one to where heightQuadGrid.h is?
And then how do i include it in my cpp file, the way I have done?

Comment: My apologies this worked. Im not sure I really understand why though. But thankyou. A more neat looking solution to this for anyone is to do
     include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

Comment: Glad it worked. When you `#include` something, the compiler looks at the "include directories", then looks for the file relative to those (including subdirectories you have in that `#include`). In your case, `heightQuadGrid` is the subdir and `heightQuadGrid.h` is the file. So you need the directory *above* that subdir so when the whole thing gets appended, the full path is valid. `include_dir/subdir/file` in other words. As you note, `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` works too - that's because in this case, it is the same directory as `../../` in your directory structure.