# CMake not finding proper header/include files in include_directories

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

Once again I am getting a "undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" error when I try to compile.  I've tried more than I can actually document in this post (because I've forgotten all that I have tried).  It is a really simple set-up and *should* compile very easily with CMake...

When I run a make on this it works just fine.  But I want to convert it to CMake for interoperability.  As you can see I have thrown my "${HEADERS}" variable in a few places, I've tried quite a few placements of it but I keep getting my error.  Depending on where I put that ${HEADER} it can also technically generate an error of "error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files"  (That applies if it **only** sits in the target_link_library declaration).

I have 2 folders:

```
Root
    Headers (contains all .h files)
    Source (contains all .cc/.cpp/.c files) (and also a CMakeLists.txt)
CMakeLists.txt
```

My root CMakeLists.txt contains the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(Framework)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
add_compile_options("-v")

add_subdirectory(Source)

#Variables for making my life easier and adding the headers
set(H Headers)
include_directories(${H})
set(S Source)
file(GLOB HEADERS
#Add any file in the headers dir
"${H}/*"
)

# Create a variable to use for main.cc
set(MAIN ${S}/main.cc ${HEADERS})

# Add the main.cc file and headers
add_executable(Framework ${MAIN} ${HEADERS})

# Add the .cc/.cpp files
target_link_libraries(Framework ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

My CMakeLists.txt in my source directory contains the following:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES
"*.cc"
"*.cpp"
)

add_library(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCES})
```

I do not have one in the headers as per, what I believe, the documentation states we don't need.

Thanks for the help.  I've looked at:

- [cmake including h files from other directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985315/cmake-including-h-files-from-other-directories)
- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.0/cmake.html (both for version 2.x and 3.x)
- [CMake Adding Headers to Projectfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654867/cmake-adding-headers-to-projectfile) -- had a potential for a solution but ended up saying "I don't know" :(
- and many other various mail lists and other sites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem here is that you're referring to the `SOURCE_FILES` target as if it was a variable. Remove the dollar sign and curly braces.

```
target_link_libraries(Framework SOURCE_FILES)
```

It also seems kind of weird that you set `include_directories` after calling `add_subdirectory`, I'd be surprised if that worked.

Overall I think you're making things more complicated than they need to be. The following should be all that's necessary.

**Top level CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Framework CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")

include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers
)

add_subdirectory(Source)
```

**Source/CMakeLists.txt**

```
# Do not use file globing because then CMake is not able to tell whether a file
# has been deleted or added when rebuilding the project.
set(HELLO_LIB_SRC
  hello.cc
)
add_library(hello ${HELLO_LIB_SRC})

set(MAIN_SRC
  main.cc
)
add_executable(hello_bin ${MAIN_SRC})
target_link_libraries(hello_bin hello)
```

**Headers/hello.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace nope
{
  std::string hello_there();
}
```

**Source/hello.cc**

```
#include <hello.h>

namespace nope
{
  std::string hello_there()
  {
    return "Well hello there!";
  }
}
```

**Source/main.cc**

```
#include <hello.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << nope::hello_there() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Do not worry about the placement of files in the build folder. That's for the install step to figure out.

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
$ make
```

Comment: You sir, a lifesaver.  I manipulated an old CMake from another project that was set up completely different; and it clearly didn't work.  So it doesn't matter where you link a library or add an executable, just as long as it exists?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When you use functions like add_executable / add_library / ... you create a target. You can depend on this target in other targets which get created after **or before** the particular target. CMake will make sure all of the dependencies are met at the end and will scream otherwise.