# How to separate header file and source file in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

My project is in the structure as follows:

```
--root: main.cpp CMakeLists.txt 

    --src: function.cpp CMakeLists.txt 

    --include: function.h
```

---

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "function.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //call module in function.hpp
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt in root directory:

```
 project(t1)
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
 add_subdirectory(src)               
 file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
     include/function.h
     src/function.cpp)            
 add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

CmakeLists.txt in src directory:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

How to write CMakelists in the root and src directory to realize separate implementation of function? And further more, how to call them in main. Possible solutions in [CMake not finding proper header/include files in include_directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937085/cmake-not-finding-proper-header-include-files-in-include-directories). But it still doesn't match my situations.

Comment: `${SOURCES}`  shouldn't contain the header file. Use `include_directories` to specify  the `include` path.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You *can* put header files among a target's sources. CMake won't try to compile them, but other tools, e.g. IDEs, can show the headers in lists/trees, which can be quite nice.

Comment: How to show include/headers in Qt trees is exactly what I desired. But I cannot quite understand specific operation you've mentioned above. Maybe you can show me how to add operations to the accepted answer below.

Comment: @Biffen thank you for your help .

Comment: solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384935/qtcreator-cmake-project-how-to-show-all-project-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in root:

```
project(t1)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include_directories(include)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

in src:

```
set(TARGET target_name)
add_executable(${TARGET} main.cpp function.cpp)
```

Comment: Your solution solved my problem perfectly if main.cpp is in src. But what if main.cpp is in root?

Comment: @Qinchen `add_executable(${TARGET} ../main.cpp function.cpp)` or `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp`

Comment: Why would you want to set your target in the src subdirectory? This strikes me as a bit messed up. I want to set my target top level and tell it to use the stuff in the src directory.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I have the same question and I found the solution.

CMakeLists.txt in root directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.3)
project(t1)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(src)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC include)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE src)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} function)
```

CMakeLists.txt in src directory:

```
include_directories(../include)
add_library(function function.cpp)
```

Thanks **Code, Tech and Tutorial** and his video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEGQKzhciKc&t=606s. This helps me to have an idea to solve this problem